# Javafx change osx menubar name

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, javafx

I am using Netbeans trying to change the title when the program runs from `java` to `Phantom`. I also would like to change where it says `phantom.Main` to `Phantom`. I am not sure if I do this in: Java, Netbeans, Netbeans priorities or the ant build.xml file (or even somewhere else). I can not find any documentation on this either. Any help on this would be great!

[image: Change Title]

Answer (score 2):

The "java" name in the (Mac OS X) application menu is only used when you run the application from within Netbeans.  If you were to package the application into a DMG, and then run the resulting app, the name of the application will appear in that location.

Comment: jpackager --name option

Answer (score 0):

You *may not* be able to do it via Netbeans or any other IDE, but you can definitely do it while creating an application bundle, using **JavaFX Ant Script**.

To get it display a custom name, change `application` name in the packaging procedure.

To know how to package your application, please visit - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30162808/1759128

For more information, refer

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_tasks.htm

Example

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_tasks.htm#CIAHEGJD

Comment: I won't use Ant for this. Is there a non-Ant solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same, after some googling I found this post which has a solution to changing the menu bar at the top, but not the menu that says "java":
[How to make an OS X menubar in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569046/how-to-make-an-os-x-menubar-in-javafx)

**EDIT:** It essentially says that that if you want to have a so called system menu bar, you have to invoke the function `setUseSystemMenuBar(true)` on the MenuBar item. One more thing to mention is that it doesn't work if there are no MenuItems in the menu.