# How to rename a JavaFX program?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Every time a JavaFX program is compiled, the logo and the name are setted as: [image: JavaFX program]

Is there anyway to change the "java" label?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javafx change osx menubar name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768839/javafx-change-osx-menubar-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get proper support for that you will have to package your code into a real application. This can be done with the new jpackage tool in JDK 14+.